# Unreal Engine 5.2 Android package failed: android-32 30.0.3 3.10.2.4988404 25.1.8937393 -noninteractive failed

Tags: android, sdk, packaging, unreal-engine5

I'm having trouble with packaging my project for Android.As soon as I start packaging an error occurs and it can't continue. The error is this:

`PackagingResults: Error: Command E:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.2\Engine\Extras\Android\SetupAndroid.bat android-32 30.0.3 3.10.2.4988404 25.1.8937393 -noninteractive failed [Exit code 4, working dir = E:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.2\Engine\Extras\Android]`

More info from Output Log

[PackagingError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhLcj.jpg)

You can see in the image that Output Log says that it Failed to install Android SDK r25b.. but in Unreal Engine Documentaion -> Android -> Development Requirements it says that the NDK (not SDK) needs to be r25b..so I'm confused

I installed the latest Android Studio on its default location

After that I read Unreal Documentation on how to set up android SDK and NDK and I tried to run packaging and had a bunch of errors that I can't really remember. And this same error I have now was between all of the others. The errors were there because I didn't set up the SDK Tools properly.So I started following this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMkl5FdtvP8&list=PLd_lmWO1xgx0LBJO3z2ELjW9jHorXf897&index=103

After installing and setting up all of the SDK,NDK and JDK files (In Android Studio and after in Unreal Engine) it started to pack. Even this "-noninteractive failed" error was not there.
But when it cooked up everything in the end I had this error message that resulted in package failure:

`Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7`

Then I found this youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAYEpiTgeXI&list=PLd_lmWO1xgx0LBJO3z2ELjW9jHorXf897&index=104

It basically helped me understand that I was missing JRE files and that I shouldn't set the location of JAVA on JDK location but on JRE location:

[JRELocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZkQn.jpg)

But I followed setting up everything in this video, even the setting up SDK and NDK Tools (Android Studio Setup part of that video)... which was clearly a mistake because after that it didn't even register the android platform as it should (It had a triangle warning sign next to it).I've managed to get back most of the settings that made it start packing before tinkering with the SDK Tools again..the emphasys on most..

So now I am back with this error that I don't know how was fixed in the first place. And when I go to SetupAndroid.bat file in the engine root, open it with Notepad++ and search for -noninteractive in order to try and see the code for google exploring about it I get only this:

```
IF "%5" == "-noninteractive" (
    set PAUSE=
) ELSE (
    set PAUSE=pause
)
```

When I try and google the error I've posted here it leads me to setting up SDK's..But some of the SDK's were set up automatically when I followed the first video from Alex Pearce and I can't remember how it was set up before following the video from Nils Gallist. These are the settings that I have now in Android Studio:

-SDK Build Tools:
[SKD Build Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Yfg.jpg)
-NDK:
[NDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfGNL.jpg)
-Command-line Tools and CMake:
[Command-line Tools and CMake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A676.jpg)

So if anyone has a solution for this it would be a lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

"D:\EpicGames\UE_5.2\Engine\Extras\Android\SetupAndroid.bat"
I just replace SetupAndroid.bat with 5.1. my 5.1 works fine so.

Here's What i changed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and it's a little finicky because the SDK and NDK requirements change with every version of Unreal Engine. Double check https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/android-development-requirements-for-unreal-engine/ for official documentation but last time I checked it was a couple versions behind.

**Step 1**
I am on Unreal Engine 5.2.1 and Using Android SDK 33. It is important that you have Android Studio version 4.0 downloaded (not Android Studio Giraffe or whatever the latest). From there download the right SDK and NDK versions as well as downloading cmdline-tools.

SDK Version: 33

NDK Version: 26.0.10792818

Android SDK Command-line Tools : 8.0

Once that is done Unreal Editor under Project Settings --> Android set...

Minimum SDK Version : 30

Target SDK Version : 33

[ProjectSettings / Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZH75.png)

**Step 2**
Next go to Project Settings --> Android SDK and set...

SDK API Level: android-29

NDK API Level: android-29

[ProjectSettings / AndroidSDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8ILb.png)

Try building! For some that is all you have to do.

**Step 3**
If that still doesn't work, you need to edit your SetupAndroid.bat file. I found mine in...

LocalDisk/ProgramFiles/EpicGames/UE_5.2/Engine/Extras/Android

[SetupAndroid.bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F85Q.png)

Open it in NotePad by right clicking and selecting "edit". Search for "SDKMANAGER" and change the code in that section to...

`set SDKMANAGER=%STUDIO_SDK_PATH%\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat IF EXIST "%SDKMANAGER%" ( echo Using sdkmanager: %SDKMANAGER% ) ELSE ( set SDKMANAGER=%STUDIO_SDK_PATH%\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat IF EXIST "!SDKMANAGER!" ( echo Using sdkmanager: !SDKMANAGER! ) ELSE ( echo Unable to locate sdkmanager.bat. Did you run Android Studio and install cmdline-tools after installing? %PAUSE% exit /b 3 ) )`

Now go to
LocalDisk/Users/*UserName*/AppData/Local/Android/SDK/cmdline-tools

This shows you which versions of Android Command Line Tools. My latest was 8.0. Change the folder name from *8.0* to *latest* and then run the SetupAndroid.bat file.

**Step 4**
Re-open Unreal Editor and try to build again. If it still doesn't work, try downloading different versions of Android SDK Command-line Tools (look back at Step 1) and change its folder's name to *latest* (see Step 3)

This worked for me. I don't know the specifics for other Unreal Engine Versions but the biggest differences would be changing SDK and NDK versions. Hope this helps!